# Why spring.jpa.properties. prefix is not always required in Spring Boot properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, application.properties

I learning Spring boot and found that in some examples use the same properties **with the prefix** `spring.jpa.properties` while other do it **without prefix**.

**For instance:**
The article explains second level cahche https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache and autor shows example of needed properties ( [example on autor's gitHub](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/007603b3040132f42c898f12b307e6ff6d8fa1cd/persistence-modules/spring-hibernate-5/src/main/resources/persistence-h2.properties#L12)):

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

But it did not work for me, and I spent few hours loking for the reason, but then i noticed, someone use prefix `spring.jpa.properties.` to get it working ([Exact moment from video lesson](https://youtu.be/79s1d16ZltU?t=404)):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

Which perfectly worked for me.

**So my questions are:**

- why are they working in different way?
- how to understand which properties in which cases requires this prefix?
- is it probably something related to my project settings OR Spring Boot version?
- any other suggestions are appreciated :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: its spring boot configuration . https://thorben-janssen.com/configuring-spring-data-jpa-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Because it is Spring Boot who configures the JPA entitymanager here (and the guide you follow doesn't use Spring Boot). Spring Boot has some generic JPA properties exposed as `spring.jpa` however you can extend JPA (at leat hibernate) and it isn't doable to have properties for all extensions to hibernate (there are about 5 caching implementations for instance). So if you want to set some non exposed property you need to prefix them with `spring.jpa.properties` and they will be passed on to the JPA provider directly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you very much! It does explain all what I need)
You could write it as the Answer, so I could mark as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things in play here. First the tutorial you use is using *plain* `Spring Framework` and *not* `Spring Boot`. Which means a manually configured `EntityManagerFactory` on which you directly can set the provider specific properties. Like `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache`.

As you decided to use `Spring Boot` you don't have a manually configured `EntityManagerFactory` (although you could!). Which means you are using an autoconfigured `EntityManagerFactory`. Properties for this reside in the `spring.jpa` namespace for properties.

As it isn't feasible to specify properties for each and every extension for Hibernate (or other JPA providers) only some commonly used ones are exposed like `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` and a few provider specific ones in the `spring.jpa.hibernate` namespace. However to set all the other properties in an autoconfigured way there needed to be something else. Hence the `spring.jpa.properties` prefix. Anything specified in there will be passed on as is (without the said prefix ofcourse) to the `EntityManagerFactory` for configuration.